# PowerBI Splitting a delimited column into duplicate rows

Tags: forms, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am working with a customer survey in MS Forms, there are 2 questions that have multiple selections. What I want to know is, how do I split these columns into new rows while duplicating the data in the other columns?

I know how to split the column by delimiter, I'm just struggling to figure out the correct approach to split the columns and duplicate the rows.

Here are the two columns, crossed out for sensitive info, there are about 10+ additional columns with data that I would like to be duplicated with each split.

[image: The two columns]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these bellow steps-

**Input:**

[image]

**Step one:**
[image]

**Step two:**
[image]

**Output:**

[image]